# how to make loadable kernel module on solaris? no linux

Tags: unix, module, kernel, solaris, kernel-module

## 1. how to create loadable kernel module on solaris 11?

- simple loadable kernel module (hello world).
- I searched, but only showed how to create a Linux kernel module.
- in linux, header linux/kernel.h, but not included header on solaris

## 2. how to compile loadable kernel module on solaris 11?

- gcc -D_KERNEL -m64 -c cpluscplus.cpp
- Is it appropriate to compile as above?
- 64bit, x86

Comment: "I searched, but only showed how to create a Linux kernel module." - Just tried to google for "build solaris kernel module", one of the first references is https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5789/fgouv/index.html.

Comment: One thing to be aware of, as it's not well-documented:  if you don't provide a `driver.conf` file, your kernel module won't attach and the error message won't be very useful.  See [`man driver.conf`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29042/driver.conf-4.html) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the minimal hello world kernel module I can come up with:

```
#include <sys/modctl.h>
#include <sys/cmn_err.h>

/*
 * Module linkage information for the kernel.
 */
static struct modlmisc modlmisc = {
        &mod_miscops, "test module"
};

static struct modlinkage modlinkage = {
        MODREV_1, (void *)&modlmisc, NULL
};


int
_init(void)
{
        return (mod_install(&modlinkage));
}

int
_fini(void)
{
        return (mod_remove(&modlinkage));
}

int
_info(struct modinfo *modinfop)
{
        cmn_err(CE_NOTE, "hello kernel");
        return (mod_info(&modlinkage, modinfop));
}
```

Compiling this as 64-bit binary with Oracle Developer Studio 12.6 and the Solaris linker like so:

```
cc -D_KERNEL -I include -m64 -c foomod.c
ld -64 -z type=kmod -znodefs -o foomod foomod.o
```

For GCC you will likely need a distinct set of options.

Then load it with:

```
modload ./foomod
```

This will complain about signature verification. This is innocuous unless you are running the system with Verified Boot enabled.

Check that module is loaded:

```
# modinfo -i foomod
ID  LOADADDR         SIZE   INFO REV NAMEDESC
312 fffffffff7a8ddc0 268    --   1   foomod (test module)
# dmesg | tail -1
Mar 16 12:22:57 ST091 foomod: [ID 548715 kern.notice] NOTICE: hello kernel
```

This works on Solaris 11.4 SRU 33 running on x86 machine (VirtualBox instance in fact).